# OSMNX: How do I create a graph that has a union custom query?

Tags: python, osmnx

My goal is to determine a long distance driving route from A to B, and then within a half mile radius of that driving route, determine:

- The road network
- Gas stations
- Hotels

I am almost there:

- I first get the driving route as a LINESTRING.
- I then create a
  polygon along the LINESTRING with a radius of 800 meters (half a
  mile).
- I then use OSMNX to download and plot a graph of the road
  network using a custom filter that excludes pedestrian ways, cycleways, etc.

```
    cf_allroads = '["area"!~"yes"]["highway"!~"cycleway|footway|path|pedestrian|steps|track|corridor|proposed|construction|bridleway|abandoned|platform|raceway"]'

    G = ox.graph_from_polygon ( polygon = route_buffer_polygon,
                               custom_filter=cf_allroads,
                               simplify=False
                               )
```

How do I specify the custom filter to be the union of:

- The road network
- Gas stations (amenity=fuel)
- Hotels (tourism=hotel)

I have searched the documentation for over an hour without luck.  I can do any one of them successfully, but not the union of all three!

I am also open to querying and obtaining multiple graphs, and then combining them into one, but am not sure how to do that.